Split dataste into train/test - but guarantee that a certain key/identifier does not exist in both
I need to split a dataset into train/test with the following constraints:

The approximate train/test ration split is honored (for example 70/30)
Each row in the dataset has a key. Those keys are not unique, meaning I could have 1000s rows with 1 key, and another 2 rows with another key. I want to guarantee that the same key does not exist in both the train and test sets.

I tried everything online (including similar topics here), like GroupKFold etc. But it seems I cannot get anything to do that.
Any ideas?

If you need to ensure that specific IDs are not shared between your training and test datasets, you should use the groups argument in the splitter to account for them.
A good approach is to utilize the GroupShuffleSplit class from sklearn.model_selection, which allows you to split the data based on group labels, ensuring that no group appears in both the train and test sets.
For more details, check out this related question: How to generate a train-test-split based on a group ID?. There, you'll find a clear example of how to set the groups argument when using GroupShuffleSplit.

I already tried it. It does not work for me. For some reason it considers the full number of samples as the unique number of groups, and extracts the percentage from there. So I end up with 50K + 106 (train/test)

To be clear, the IDs are not balanced. Some IDs have 100s of samples, others have only 1. the split function takes the number of unique groups, and apparently uses the test_size to sample the groups, then use them

Could you share the snippet where you're calling GroupShuffleSplit, and add comments explaining the variables used as arguments? @ShadiIskander

Edit: this did what is expected out of it. The errors I mentioned in the comments I deleted were because of some pre-processing that messed up the groups.
However, this assigns the test to train ratio to the groups themselves. Thus the final sample ratio is not the same, and of course no stratification is done, so there is no guarantee on the class/label distribution at the end. But thats fine for me
